# "::" in php for calling non-static functions works out of class

Tags: php

as far as i know, `::` is using for calling static functions and base class functions in a subclass. and as far as i know, usually we have to create an instance of a class for using it out of the class.

```
class a 
{
    public function foo()
    {
       //
    }
}
```

for using this class:

```
$instance = new a();
$instance->foo();
```

but its possible that we call the `foo` function without creating any instance and only using `::`. for example the following code is written out of class and works well:

```
a::foo();
```

why does it work? and how?

Comment: It's called the `Scope Resolution Operator`: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Comment: *(related)* [What does that symbol mean in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`::` is the scope resolution operator.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

From PHP's docs:

```
<?php
class MyClass {
    const CONST_VALUE = 'A constant value';
}

$classname = 'MyClass';
echo $classname::CONST_VALUE; // As of PHP 5.3.0

echo MyClass::CONST_VALUE;
?>
```

It is like `->`, but has some special semantics.

Comment: what about accessing properties with the scope resolution operator?

Answer (score 4):

Calling a non-static method with the `Class::method()` syntax invokes the method but raises an error if it attempts to access `$this`. It is essentially a hold-over from the (very minimal) object-oriented programming implementation of PHP4, and it will generate a warning in PHP5; this isn't correct behaviour from an OOP standpoint, and you shouldn't rely on it.